# Magento2: Custom email template from Admin

Tags: magento2, event-observer, customer, email-templates

I am trying to send an email to the customer once it saves from the Admin.
I have called my observer `adminhtml_customer_save_after`. Observer called but email template not working.
my code is below.

```
$templateOptions = array('area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND, 'store' => $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId());

$templateVars = array(
    'store' => $this->_storeManager->getStore(),
    'customer_name' => 'John Doe',
    'message'   => 'Hello World!!.'
);

$from = array('email' => "ravi@examle.com", 'name' => 'Ravi');
$to = array('email' => "ravi@gmail.com", 'name' => 'Ravi');

$this->_inlineTranslation->suspend();
$transport = $this->_transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier('hello_template')
    ->setTemplateOptions($templateOptions)
    ->setTemplateVars($templateVars)
    ->setFrom($from)
    ->addTo($to)
    ->getTransport();

$transport->sendMessage();

$this->_inlineTranslation->resume();
```

Can anyone please look and tell me what I miss?

Answer (score 0):

Try below code for it

```
$templateOptions = array('area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND, 'store' => \Magento\Store\Model\Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID);


        $templateVars = array(
                            'store' => \Magento\Store\Model\Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID,
                            'customer_name' => 'John Doe',
                            'message'   => 'Hello World!!.'
                        );


        $from = array('email' => "ravi@examle.com", 'name' => 'Ravi');
        $to = array('email' => "ravi@gmail.com", 'name' => 'Ravi');

        $postObject = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject();
        $postObject->setData($templateVars);

        $this->_inlineTranslation->suspend();
        $transport = $this->_transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier('hello_template')
                        ->setTemplateOptions($templateOptions)
                        ->setTemplateVars(['data' => $postObject])
                        ->setFrom($from)
                        ->addTo($to)
                        ->getTransport();


        $transport->sendMessage();


        $this->_inlineTranslation->resume();
```

Comment: sorry not working..